# JavaFx (JDK8) - Easiest way to style buttons in a ContextMenu?

Tags: css, user-interface, java-8, javafx-8

I have a TableView with 8 TableColumns and every TableColumn has a ContextMenu with a bunch of CheckBox - MenuItems and three buttons.

The problem is that everything is lined up vertically (like a stack) but I want the buttons to be in a HBox so that they are placed next to each other. Unfortunately I can't find any explanation on this topic.

Is there away to achieve this with css or do I need to implement my own control ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a ContextMenu is not the best component to start from. I did a quick check with the three buttons within an HBox that is set as graphic to MenuItem. Two side effects of ContextMenu:

1. Graphic and text are layed out in two columns - not the desired
   layout.
2. The MenuItem (container of the HBox) reacts to mouseover events - not desired too.

In similar situations, where a ContentMenu brought along too much special behaviour, I used a javafx.stage.Popup (window without decoration) and simply populated it with the desired controls - in your case three checkboxes and the three buttons, packed in appropriate layout containers (e.g., a VBox and an HBox for the buttons).